# SwiftUI MVVM logic for initializing view models with parallel paths

Tags: swift, swiftui, mvvm

Suppose I have two paths in my app:
**X** -> A -> B -> C and
**X** -> E -> F -> G.
Now let's imagine views, **B** and **F** both share view model **Alpha**, and there is an equal chance of the user navigating to either view first. Although this is a simplified demo, and using @EnvironmentObject when starting out in the root view would be my choice here, let's imagine a much more complex application with many views, and many view models where initializing and passing all view models into the environment at the entry point into the application would be computationally demanding.

Should I just used @ObservedObject for each view/view model in this case if/when the user navigates to the view, or is there a way I can add logically to pass the view model to the environment logically depending on which view is reached first. I want to make sure I am not creating any memory leaks and performing extra steps, so wondering what the most efficient way to do this would be for parallel views. Thanks

Comment: Look into dependency injection

Answer (score 0):

Usually just a single `environmentObject` that holds the arrays of model structs. Pass them down the View structs as `let`s for read access or `@Binding var`s for write access.